# Wifi connection dropped after docker start

Tags: networking, docker, wifi

I am logged in to my Lubuntu 16.04.2 LTS Server over Wifi and every time I start a docker container my connection gets dropped. Because I am relatively new to docker I can only guess that is has something to do with dockers virtual network creation. I should also mentioned that I disabled ipv6, but it makes no differences if enabled.

Here is my [syslog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wh265hc9pls0qcl/syslog.txt?raw=1), it shows what happens when I am running `sudo docker run -it ubuntu bash`. I can see the container/ubuntu prompt for 2-3 seconds before it freezes. Running it with `--net=host` works, but is not what I want.

`ifconfig` shows

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:8d:8b:b7:4c  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:162 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:536 (536.0 B)  TX bytes:9678 (9.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:538 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:49592 (49.5 KB)  TX bytes:49592 (49.5 KB)

vethee1cf14 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ba:53:4c:08:89:64  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:8 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:167 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:648 (648.0 B)  TX bytes:9888 (9.8 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:06:69:5d:ba:f6  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3082 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2916 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:556197 (556.1 KB)  TX bytes:569381 (569.3 KB)
```

`docker network inspect bridge` shows

```
[
    {
    "Name": "bridge",
    "Id": "8ec46d17f5cba798c8aba5c8457e019dcb24eade1285054f59c3430c33ff74f8",
    "Created": "2017-03-04T10:44:27.966018717+01:00",
    "Scope": "local",
    "Driver": "bridge",
    "EnableIPv6": false,
    "IPAM": {
        "Driver": "default",
        "Options": null,
        "Config": [
            {
                "Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1"
            }
        ]
    },
    "Internal": false,
    "Attachable": false,
    "Containers": {},
    "Options": {
        "com.docker.network.bridge.default_bridge": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_icc": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade": "true",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.host_binding_ipv4": "0.0.0.0",
        "com.docker.network.bridge.name": "docker0",
        "com.docker.network.driver.mtu": "1500"
    },
    "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

With docker stopped `ip a` shows

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:06:69:5d:ba:f6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.178.21/24 brd 192.168.178.255 scope global wlp2s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::f606:69ff:fe5d:baf6/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:6f:0c:38:7a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

What happens to my Wifi connection? Any help is appreciated. If more information would be helpful, please let me know.

**UPDATE**

Thx for you help. According to the responses I got so far, something seems to be wrong with my network configuration.

`cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` shows

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` shows

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Since I did no special configuration everything looks fine to me. Any suggestions where else I could look for information or how to work around the problem?

**UPDATE**

`nmcli dev` shows

```
DEVICE       TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
docker0      bridge    connected    docker0    
wlp2s0       wifi      unavailable  --         
vethf9342a9  ethernet  unmanaged    --         
lo           loopback  unmanaged    --
```

while docker is running and

```
DEVICE   TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION 
docker0  bridge    connected  docker0    
wlp2s0   wifi      connected  meins      
lo       loopback  unmanaged  --
```

when docker is stopped.

**UPDATE**

Added the following lines to `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` to make NetworkManager ignore the docker interfaces.

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0;interface-name:veth*
```

Network manager ignored the interfaces, but the problem persists. So my guess is, that is a problem with my DHCP configuration.

**UPDATE**

There really seems to be a problem with the DHCP client. Disabling it helps. Any suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: Can you include the output of `docker network inspect bridge` in your question. Also, with docker stopped and the wifi working, what does `ip a` show?

Comment: Can you also include the full `docker run` command (or compose file) you are using to start the container?

Comment: @BMitch: Included the full command in the description. - Indeed the exact command doesn't seem to matter. All commands that create a virtual docker network cause my wifi to disconnect.

Comment: Something is wonky with your network config.   Your container network looks like it's trampling over your host network.

veth48067d8: using static address 192.168.178.21/24
wlp2s0: using static address 192.168.178.21/24

Comment: This is looking more like a networkmanager and/or config issue.   NM should ignore veth* devices.    What is the result of "nmcli dev" both prior and during docker execution?

Comment: i am facing the same issue, @NaN did you find any solution for the same ??? i can't find any answer here.

Comment: @Keyur Patel: There seems to be a problem with my DHCP client. Everything works fine as soon as I disable it.

Answer (score 9):

Same problem on `Ubuntu 18.04`.

I think add the following content into file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` have sovled this problem:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker0;interface-name:veth*
```

You also need to do some other things:

1. stop all your docker containers;
2. restart network by `sudo service network-manager restart`, now your wifi should work well;
3. start your docker containers again, my wifi is still working at this moment.

Mar 14, 2019

ref: https://askubuntu.com/a/1009402/620445

Answer (score 2):

The lines that stand out to me from your logs are:

```
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi NetworkManager[1054]: <info>  [1488372884.3614] device (docker0): link connected
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: veth48067d8: IAID 3a:d3:8a:28
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: veth48067d8: using static address 192.168.178.21/24
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: wlp2s0: preferring 192.168.178.21 on veth48067d8
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: veth48067d8: adding route to 192.168.178.0/24
Mar  1 13:54:44 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: veth48067d8: adding default route via 192.168.178.1
```

In my own environment, after NetworkManager sees the link connected, I only see the following:

```
Mar  5 12:32:39 bmitch-asusr556l NetworkManager[827]: <info> devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/veth365c591, iface: veth365c591)
Mar  5 12:32:39 bmitch-asusr556l NetworkManager[827]: <info> (vethf29a6bb): link connected
Mar  5 12:32:41 bmitch-asusr556l avahi-daemon[835]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface vethf29a6bb.IPv6 with address fe80::34c0:66ff:fe89:26ec.
Mar  5 12:32:41 bmitch-asusr556l avahi-daemon[835]: New relevant interface vethf29a6bb.IPv6 for mDNS.
Mar  5 12:32:41 bmitch-asusr556l avahi-daemon[835]: Registering new address record for fe80::34c0:66ff:fe89:26ec on vethf29a6bb.*.
```

My questions in the comments above where to figure out if you had somehow hardcoded your container IP to the 192.168.178.x network. Since that's not happening, you should see containers spin up with a 172.17.0.x address. There appears to be either a misconfiguration of NetworkManager or dhcpd in your environment that is trying to give an IP to the docker container (veth) with the same IP used by your wireless (wlp2s0), and the container is then listed as the preferred connection.

Comment: Didn't scroll down enough to see this.   Something is very wrong with your network config.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the internet in my Ubuntu 18.04 stopped working after starting docker, and remained off even after stopping the docker service.

What I did that solved my problem was to remove all the docker networks with `docker network prune` and the internet started working again.

I'm not sure what was the problem, tough I guess it might be related to some firewall rules applied incorrectly (for some reason), or some conflict between networks, that affected the internet, but it's just a guess.

The problem with the OP might be related to some misconfigured network, that is reused by default when starting the container, but not reused when `net=host`, so removing it should solve the problem (if this is the problem, of course).

Comment: Fixed for myself as well, what the hell..

Answer (score 0):

I've gone through syslog posted by you, it seems there is some authentication issue:

```
Mar  1 13:54:45 kodi kernel: [351489.718503] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 34:31:c4:0c:bf:24 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Mar  1 13:54:45 kodi dhcpcd[1240]: veth48067d8: carrier acquired
Mar  1 13:54:45 kodi wpa_supplicant[1259]: wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=34:31:c4:0c:bf:24 reason=3 locally_generated=1
Mar  1 13:54:45 kodi NetworkManager[1054]: <warn>  [1488372885.1783] sup-iface[0x23b4210,wlp2s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Mar  1 13:54:45 kodi kernel: [351489.751908] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
```

For time being what all I can say is, please got through the links I'm pasting below:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/#logs-1

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/articles/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04

If this doesn't solve your issue, please post more appropriate logs, by following debugging steps.

Answer (score 0):

No expert in this field but the way I was able to overcome similar issue for wired connection was just moving the local network addresses in router settings to something unorthodox like 69.69.69.xx.

Can't pin down the reason behind network drops but i guess it is tied to docker virtual networks interfering whit physical one